# type mismatch in flexboxlayout

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Google FlexBox in my project. When I set my it to recyclerview I get an error typemismatch.

Here is the code that I have error

```
    val flexBox = FlexboxLayoutManager(this).apply {
        flexWrap = FlexWrap.WRAP
        flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
        alignItems = AlignItems.STRETCH
    }
    mRecyclerViewMyGroups.apply {
        layoutManager = flexBox
        adapter = mMyGroupsAdapter
    }
```

I get the typemismatch in flexBox in the line layoutManager = flexBox

what is the mistake I have made how to resolve that

Comment: what is the exact type mismatch?

Comment: this is what it shows                                                                                      Type mismatch.
Required:
RecyclerView.LayoutManager?
Found:
FlexboxLayoutManager

Comment: Are you using androidx? Try just building the app, it might work. I have the same issue with another recyclerview library. There is an error in android studio but it works fine

Comment: didnt work when I tried building, build failed with the error type mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your FlexBox version in `gradle.build`.

From [FlexBox's GitHub](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

> Note that starting from 1.1.0, the library is expected to use with AndroidX. Please migrate to AndroidX if you use 1.1.0 or above.
>
> Please use 1.0.0 if you haven't migrated to AndroidX.

I used FlexBox 1.1.0 and encountered the same error, change it to 1.0.0 and the error is gone.

Comment: yeah actually that was the problem and I have resolved that, but anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just changed the code to the below and it worked,

```
    val flexlayout = FlexboxLayoutManager(FlexDirection.ROW)
    mRecyclerViewMyGroups.layoutManager = flexlayout
```